# NodeJS MongoDB Why findById() works on startup and in router POST but not when I execute the file

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Driving me nuts here.

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Database'))

app.use(express.json())

// route for Customer/Vendor Registration Paperform to Quickbooks
const qbo1Router = require('./routes/qbo1')
app.use('/qbo1', qbo1Router)

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log('Server Started'))
```

./routes/qbo1.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()

const RefreshToken = require('../models/refreshtoken.js'); // storing refreshToken in database schema RefreshToken

find()

async function find() {
    const token = await RefreshToken.findById('61355917fedd0f00166e4e08')
    console.log(token)
}
```

./models/refreshtoken.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const refreshTokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    token: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('RefreshToken', refreshTokenSchema)
```

find() function in qbo1 executes successfully on startup -

```
2021-09-21T06:49:06.612008+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-09-21T06:49:06.483800+00:00 app[web.1]: Server Started
2021-09-21T06:49:06.747948+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to Database
2021-09-21T06:49:06.761366+00:00 app[web.1]: {
2021-09-21T06:49:06.761367+00:00 app[web.1]: _id: 61355917fedd0f00166e4e08,
2021-09-21T06:49:06.761369+00:00 app[web.1]: token: <mytokenhere>,
2021-09-21T06:49:06.761370+00:00 app[web.1]: __v: 0
2021-09-21T06:49:06.761370+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

So why is it when I execute that file ('node ./routes/qbo1.js'), I get the timeout error below?

```
MongooseError: Operation `refreshtokens.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:197:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
```

Also maybe of note is I have that same findById call in qbo1 router.post and it also executes successfully.  So again why won't it when I'm executing the file? Trying to reuse this code in a scheduled job and need to get that token.

Comment: Where is the code for connecting to the DB?

Comment: @eol sorry wanted to try to keep the post as short as possible but yes I can see how that's relevant :) updated, thank you for looking

Comment: I think I figured out the problem here but don't know why or how it's happening - mongoose connection disconnecting, ie I checked mongoose.connection.readyState and it equals 0 (disconnected).

Tried checking for that and then await mongoose.connect which works but then for some reason the process isn't closing (again, this only happens when I execute the file).

Comment: continued this discussion and answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69277173/nodejs-why-is-mongoose-disconnecting-and-only-when-i-execute-a-file-mind-you/69279302#69279302